# Where can I find underwater slides?

Tags: where-on-earth, swimming

Someone showed me a picture of an underwater slide from an image site a while back. This got me interested, as I love the sea. And drifting on a little current between fish sounded like heaven to me.

After a little Googling, I managed to find this picture, which is in the [Atlantis Hotel](http://www.uniqhotels.com/atlantis-hotel-dubai), in Dubai.

[image: underwater slide from uniqhotels.com]

Are there any other places that have underwater slides? I would love one that actually goes through the sea, not an aquarium, like the above, but I can see how that would be difficult.

Comment: That looks amazing...

Comment: I did the Atlantis Dubai underwater slide and it is simply amazing. I only wished it would last longer :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's one at the [Golden nugget](http://www.goldennugget.com/lasvegas/pool_thetank.asp) in Las Vegas:

[image]

According to this [list of waterslides](http://www.placesyoullsee.com/40-insane-waterslides-that-you-have-to-see-to-believe/), there is the Dolphin Plunge at Aquatica Sea World in Orlando, Florida.

[image]

As well as the Atlantis in the Bahamas that @Johns-305 mentions:

[image]

[Aquatica San Antonio](https://aquaticabyseaworld.com/en/sanantonio/) has one that goes through a stingray tank:
[image]

Also one in [Tenerife](http://www.tenerifewaterpark.com/). Watch the video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1WtIQ09Vs-4).

Comment: Not sure you could call that last one a slide since they're riding rafts, but probably relevant nonetheless. (I would just call that an underwater tunnel, probably.)

Comment: @jpmc26 I quite like the look of it anyway, it's an underwater pool-thing! Too bad all of these things are so far away (I live in Europe), but an awesome list nonetheless! Didn't expect there to be some many.

Comment: I watched a video of someone going through the Atlantis shark tube. It's so quick, you wouldn't see anything. Maybe the raft thing is better for the view

Answer (score 7):

Atlantis in the Bahamas also has two similar attractions.

Sorry, there are none that use open water since they need to control the entire experience.